# Where is the format of the file `.bzr.log` documented?

Tags: bazaar

Where is the format of the file `.bzr.log` documented?

Answer (score 4):

.bzr.log is not supposed to be machine-readable format, it's debug log in human-readable format, in which different parts of bzrlib write some runtime information.

As of today standard Python library `logging` used for writing to .bzr.log.
You can find the `note/info/warning/mutter` methods in bzrlib/trace.py module.

Answer (score 1):

See: [Bazaar User Reference](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.0/en/user-reference/index.html) [Log formats](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.0/en/user-reference/index.html#log-formats) section.