# How to avoid .bzr.log (bazaar log file) being created or configure it to be in ~/.bazaar/ instead of ~/?

Tags: linux, windows, configuration, dvcs, bazaar

Is there a way to tell `bzr` not to log everything into `~/.bzr.log` or alternatively configure it to drop the log file into ~/.bazaar/` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [environment variable `BZR_LOG`](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.0/en/user-reference/index.html#environment-variables) allows to

- suppress the creation of the log file by setting it to `/dev/null` on unixoid systems and `NUL` on Windows.
- create the log file in an alternative path by pointing it to that path, e.g. `export BZR_LOG=$HOME/.bazaar/bzr.log` on a Linux.

#### Configuration:

- In Linux and other unixoid systems you can either use the system-wide setting under `/etc/profile` or `$HOME/.profile` (or `$HOME/.bash_profile` and `$HOME/.bashrc`.
- In Windows you can set the variable by right clicking `Computer` then `Properties` on the desktop, then choosing `Advanced system settings` in the left pane and from there the button `Environment variables`. The dialog which pops up (screenshot below) allows you to set new variables or edit existing ones. Here's how it looks on Windows 7: [image: Environment variable configuration dialog on Windows 7]

---

**Rationale:** it took me a while to figure it out and the search term `.bzr.log`, even when quoted, would end up with pointers to `bzr log` or this question: [Where is the format of the file `.bzr.log` documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430864/where-is-the-format-of-the-file-bzr-log-documented) None of this was particularly helpful, so I thought I'd share the found fact Q&A style for future internauts researching that same topic.